# Problem concerning inner product of a linear transformation and matrix transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonality

> Let $L: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be a linear map with standard matrix $A$ and let $\left \langle  , \right \rangle$ denote the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^k$. If the matrix $B$ satisfies the relation $$\left \langle  A\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w} \right \rangle = \left \langle \mathbf{v} , B\mathbf{w} \right \rangle$$ for all vectors $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^k$, show that $B = A^T$.

I don't know where to start on this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You just need to know that the standard scalar product can be written using matrix multiplication:

- $\left \langle \mathbf{v} , B\mathbf{w} \right \rangle = v^T (Bw)$
- Now, use associativity of matrix multiplication and $(M^T)^T= M$ and $(MN)^T = N^TM^T$:
  $$v^T (Bw) = (v^TB)w = (v^T(B^T)^T)w = (B^Tv)^Tw = \left \langle \mathbf{B^Tv} , \mathbf{w} \right \rangle$$